# Output of 'date +%a' always in system-language?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, cronjob

Does `date +%a` output always the weekday in the system language?

No matter if in bash, sh or cronjob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, except it's not "system language" in general, but specifically the value of `LANG` or `LC_TIME` environment variables. Now, whether those variables are set or not *may* indeed depend on how the script is started.

For example, in some Linux distributions, the locale environment is set through pam_env and will be present everywhere – local, SSH, cron, etc. But in some other distributions, the environment is set through /etc/profile which *only* applies to interactive sh/bash logins but not batch ones.

The most reliable option is to specify the desired locale directly within your script.

For example, if you run `env LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 date +%a` then you will always get English output, no matter what the global system language is. And if you run `env LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8 date +%a` then the output will be in German, and so on.

*(All locale-related functions first look at `LC_something`, e.g. LC_TIME or LC_MESSAGES, and if that's not set, they look at the general `LANG`.)*

Note that the locale has to be made available system-wide first, using `locale-gen` or similar tools. Use `locale -a` to check which ones are currently available.

Answer (score 0):

It's already specified in the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)

```
%a     locale's abbreviated weekday name (e.g., Sun)
```

So yes, the name is the locale's name